# What is the single word for something that is both lightweight and strong?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to describe a jacket that is very lightweight but also strong and durable. 'Efficient' is as close I've been able to get.

Comment: Spider silk. Duralumin. Graphene. Mithril. Meaning to say, you'll have to roll with a metaphor. And you'll need to pick carefully, as not everyone knows all of these, but then again, absolutely no one knows what the heck an "efficient jacket" is.

Comment: 'shell' is often used for light and strong ... so much so it's a type of outer jacket

Comment: a single word?  That will be a tough one!

Comment: [titanium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titanium):   "strength-to-density ratio, the highest of any metallic element."  Spider silk is probably stronger, but titanium sounds strong.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too specific.

Comment: *performance* as in *performance outerwear*.  High performance is implied.

Answer (score -1):

Not a single word, but the term of choice in the industry is "**high strength to weight ratio**" or "**high specific strength**".

[This article titled "New process allows for stronger, lighter, flexible steel"](https://phys.org/news/2015-02-stronger-lighter-flexible-steel.html) says:

> Annealed microstructure of **high-specific-strength steel** (HSSS).

But for jackets, I'd just go with "*lightweight yet highly durable*".